# How to properly turn the page of a UIPageViewController from a DataViewController?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, uipageviewcontroller

I want to be able to turn my UIPageViewController as a result of an event on a particular page.  Using the Page View template in Xcode, what is the proper way to achieve this?  I was thinking of just having DataViewController and ModelController contain a reference to the UIPageViewController in RootViewController and then use the [(UIPageViewController *) setViewControllers] method, but that seems sloppy.  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UIPageViewController is already accessible from the DataViewController.  All UIViewController subclasses have a field called "[parentViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIViewController/parentViewController)" that points at the UIViewController subclass that owns them (which a UIPageViewController uses).

If you want to change the page, just call

```
[((UIPageViewController*)self.parentViewController) setViewControllers:
        target direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationForward completion:nil];
```

Comment: great, got it now.  fyi though, I needed to add a property to dataviewcontroller that referenced the modelviewcontroller so i could get the next and previous dataviewcontrollers.  not sure if i should do that or just have two properties for each page that reference the next and previous pages.

Comment: I think that directly referencing the ModelViewController is probably your best bet; saves the trouble of initializing each and every DataViewController with the previous and next views, and it also eliminates any concerns if you edit your model while on a page (if you say, remove the next page, you'd also have to remember to update all of the references to that page).

Comment: @Marty Can you please post the code showing its functionality, the complete method.